# Wordpress adding in site URL to header links

Tags: php, functions, menus, url-rewriting

A little information: I am developing a one page theme that uses posts as sections on the main page. I have created code that allows users to add a menu item in the post page from a meta box when they create a section and it then creates a special ID for the section and adds it to the post and also creates a menu link for each section that has been given a name. The reason for this is because I plan on having the menu link move directly to that section when it is clicked.

So here is the dilemma: My code loops through each section and adds only the ones that have been given a custom name to the menu, just like it should. The problem though is that it is adding the website URL into the header link along with the url it has been given.

This is how it **should** appear: #SectionTwo

This is how it appears: mysite.com/#SectionTwo

I am not sure what exactly is adding this, I don't think it is my code for this but I will include it anyways. Does anyone have any ideas to what the issue could be?

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&orderby=rand&cat=-52');
        foreach($lastposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <li<?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>>


<?php if(!esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newtheme_section_id', true) == NULL) ) : ?>

    <a href="#<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newtheme_section_id', true) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newtheme_section_id', true) ); ?></a>

        </li>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Is the URL from your source code or just a DOM inspector?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean. If you are talking about when I mentioned that I don't think it is my source code, I actually meant this code I posted. I was thinking it was a rewrite issue, but I might be wrong. I am pretty new to php and wp development.

Comment: `<a href="#foo">` will be shown as `<a href="http://example.com/#foo">` by a browser. Did you see the long URL in your source code?

Comment: ahh okay I understand. It is a short URL in the source code and a long URL in the browser.

Comment: That’s normal, not a problem.

Comment: Exactly like you showed. How can I correct this?

Comment: Okay thanks. I haven't added the code to scroll to the target yet, I just assumed it was going to be an issue.